# Curl cookies storage

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I've coded a `PHP` script to simulate a Web browser. Basically, its job is to `fetch` an `Url`, store the associated `cookies` and parse it to get some data.

It was working well until monday in the afternoon, but unexpectedly **it no longer stores `cookies`** in the required directory. I assume my code hasn't been updated nor modified.

The directory, where the `cookies` are supposed to go, has `CHMOD 755`.

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
$options = array(
   CURLOPT_URL               => $url,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1,
   CURLOPT_HEADER            => 0,
   CURLOPT_FAILONERROR       => 1,
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT         => $this->user_agent,
   CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT    => 30,
   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => 0,   
   CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    => 1,
   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS         => 10,
   CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER       => 1,
   CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION     => $reset_cookies ? 1 : 0,
   CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR         => $this->cookies_file,
   CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE        => $this->cookies_file,
   CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST   => 'TLSv1',
);

// Add headers
if (isset($custom_headers))
{
   $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $custom_headers;
}

// Add POST data
if (isset($post_data))
{
   $options[CURLOPT_POST]          = 1;
   $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]    = http_build_query($post_data);
}

// Attach options
curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $options);

// Execute the request and read the response
$content = curl_exec($this->curl);

// Handle any error
if (curl_errno($this->curl)) throw new Exception(curl_error($this->curl));

return $content;
```

To create the `cookie` file based on the current session `ID`, I use this code:

```
// Create a cookie file
$this->cookies_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../cookies/' . $this->session_id .'.cookie';
if (!file_exists($this->cookies_file)) file_put_contents($this->cookies_file, '');
```

**Do you know what and why this happens ?** Also, it works perfectly localy under `WAMP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the `cookies directory` permissions to `644`.